# Generate frames for graphics.newImageSheet animation

Tags: string, for-loop, lua, coronasdk

I try to build a function that generates frames list for graphics.newImageSheet.
my function print seemingly correct list "1,2,3,4,5.." but graphics.newImageSheet reject it with the following error:

```
WARNING: Sequence (fastRun) has an invalid index (0) that falls outside the rang
e of valid image sheet frame indices: 1 <= index <= 9.
```

code:

```
function generateFrames(num)
    NumFrames = num
    frames = 1
    for i=2, NumFrames, 1 do
        frames = frames .. "," .. i
    end
end

sheetData = { width=32, height=40, numFrames=9, sheetContentWidth=96, sheetContentHeight=120 }

mySheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "media/enemies/enemy-" .. type .. ".png", sheetData)

generateFrames(9)

print("frames: " .. frames)

sequenceData = {
    { name = "fastRun", frames={ frames }, time=1000, loopCount = 0 }
}
```

Comment: `frames` is not a string inside an array.  Use `start=1, count=9,` or `frames={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},` inside your sequenceData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string in `frames = {...}`, use table.

```
function generateFrames(num)
    local frameTable = {}
    NumFrames = num
    frames = 1
    for i=2, NumFrames, 1 do
        table.insert(frameTable,i)
    end
end

sheetData = { width=32, height=40, numFrames=9, sheetContentWidth=96, sheetContentHeight=120 }

mySheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "media/enemies/enemy-" .. type .. ".png", sheetData)

generateFrames(9)

print("frames: " .. frames)

sequenceData = {
    { name = "fastRun", frames=frames , time=1000, loopCount = 0 }
}
```